# Would it be off topic to ask about manufacturer's warrantees?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd like to post the following question, but I'm not sure if it would be considered off topic or not, so I'm putting it here first to see and if I get the thumbs up will post on main:

> I'm looking at a 2012 Lexus rx450h but will be moving to California soon and wonder if it will automatically qualify for California emissions? If not, can I use the VIN to determine whether it will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible problem I see with this question is that it could end up becoming too localized. Laws sometimes change, which means the emissions laws may not apply down the line.

However, I really don't think that's likely to happen anytime soon as California's government is becoming more and more controlling, not less.

Another problem is that you haven't made it clear how this relates to Maintenance and Repair, which is the biggest reason I can see to reject your question and close it as off-topic. If you can relate it to Maintenance somehow, then it *might* be considered on-topic. For instance, maybe you're concerned about maintenance being more costly due to the emissions system and requirements! :)  Hope this helps!

Comment: My question seems to have been passed muster: [How to know whether a Lexus rx450h qualifies for California Emissions standards?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/5562/382)